# System.NullReferenceException: 'Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.'

Tags: c++-cli, clr

Написал небольшую библиотеку для работы с MySQL.
Тут создаю класс lib_ типа Library

```
main_form(void)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //
    //TODO: добавьте код конструктора
    //
    lib_ = gcnew Library();
}
```

В конструкторе Library создаю тип SqlConnector

```
Library::Library() {
    sql = gcnew SqlConnector();
}
```

В конструкторе SqlConnector

```
SqlConnector::SqlConnector() {
    Devart::Data::MySql::MySqlConnection^  sql_connection = gcnew Devart::Data::MySql::MySqlConnection();
    Devart::Data::MySql::MySqlCommand^ sql_command = gcnew Devart::Data::MySql::MySqlCommand();
    Devart::Data::MySql::MySqlDataAdapter^  sql_data_adapter = gcnew Devart::Data::MySql::MySqlDataAdapter();
    Devart::Data::MySql::MySqlCommandBuilder^  sql_command_builder = gcnew Devart::Data::MySql::MySqlCommandBuilder();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выхожу из конструктора и указатели уже ни на что не указывают [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И соответственно когда я пытаюсь присвоить значение вот здесь выдает ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит? Как решить проблему?

Comment: В конструкторе у вас объявлены _локальные_ переменные.

Comment: Как же очевидно. Спасибо, помогли.

Comment: Как закрыть вопрос, не подскажите?